# Apache Kafka : receiving topics but no data from Fiware Orion Context Broker

Tags: apache-kafka, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

I have installed kafka in a new cloud instance, and i want to get data from Fiware Orion Context Broker.

I have already done this procedure on my local machine, and it worked well.

Now, when i run zookeeper and Kafka on my cloud instance, I receive automatically topics from Orion, but topics are empty. I am able to write locally a test message in a topic from a producer to a consumer, but no Orion data are pushed into my topic.

I don't have any error message, it is just empty...
And of course, I am sure that data are pushed into Orion topic.

Any idea what is the problem here ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Cygnus to push information to Kafka?

Comment: @fgalan Yes, exactly

Comment: Can you please add to your question the Cygnus logs?

Comment: @frb We are currently experiencing a VM migration due to a major upgrade of FIWARE node. I will post the Cygnus logs when we restart everything. Thanks !